# How to write cron expression for Everyday 1.00 AM and Everyday 2.00 AM

Tags: cronexpression

I am new to cron expression. I want to write cron expression for **Everyday 1.00 AM** and **Everyday 2.00 AM** ? . How can i write cron expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't mistake it should be like:

```
0 1  *   *   *    command

0 2  *   *   *    command
```

Comment: `0 0  *   *   *` refer to 1.00 Am and `0 1  *   *   *` refer to 2.00 AM, is it ?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited my answer.

Comment: I am new so please correct me if i am wrong, The first `0` represents `seconds`. Then second `1` represents `minutes` and then `hours`, `day of month`, `month`, `day of week` and then optional `year`. Shouldn't be it like `0 0 1 ? * *` for `everyday 1 A.m` and `0 0 2 ? **` for `everyday 2.00 pm`? am i right? Can you tell me please what does `* and ?` represent ? Thanks

Comment: @Basit, everything is right, except that there is no seconds. So the first is minutes and the second is hour. Then day of month, month, day of week. Seems there is no year.

Comment: check this link to know more about cron expressions  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: @ Jevgeni Smirnov sorry :) but you mean `0 0 1 ? * *` and `0 0 2 ? * *` are correct expressions for every day 1 a.m and every day 2 a.m respectively ?

Comment: @Basit, lets sayi in this way: 5 symbols would be enough. So for every day at `1.00` and `2.00` AM `0 1 * * *` and `0 2 * * *` would be enough